# Android: Lazy Image Loader causes Gallery to stutter

Tags: android, gallery

I'm using a lazy image loader, that sets an ImageView's bitmap. I can drag the gallery, and it drags smoothly until my images load in. Then while I'm dragging the gallery stutters, as if it's trying to recenter on the middle image and doesn't let me drag. I have to do a fling to get it to move and not recenter. Anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: I hope you download/store/resize images on a non-UI thread, don't you?

Comment: Yeah, I'm downloading, and storing on a background thread. I'm saving the images to files, and loading them from their respective file and setting them to an ImageView on the UI thread. Should I be doing my BitmapFactory.decodeStream call on the background thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems I was doing too much in the UI thread, which was causing the animation to stutter. Now I'm doing "less" and it's fixed.

Comment: i'm having the exact same issue. i'm using a "lazy" image view, which works great for other uses such as a spinner, but in gallery, it keeps popping the middle image back to the center when i scroll. i'm hoping you can provide a few more details as to have you solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Android, unfixed for ten months: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16171

It will occur whenever a child of the Gallery does a `layout()`.